# C# collection with object proxy objects and Equals

Tags: c#, list, proxy, equals, nsubstitute

I had a problem with using .NET collections (List and HashSet) with object with overridden Equals method.

The context (code is below):

1. I have a base class where I implement Equals(object) by calling another method (either Equals(EntityBase<>) or with completely different name where I compare Ids of these two object.
2. I have a concrete class derived from base class.
3. I create a collection (basically a navigation property of another object).
4. In the test I create object proxy with the help of NSubstitute (internally uses Castle), but in real world it can be EntityFramework or NHibernate proxy.
5. After I put the object in the collection, the collection cannot find it or another object with the same id.
6. I cannot remove the object from the collection.

As a workaround I had to duplicate the code of Equals(EntityBase<>) in the Equals method, which solved the problem.

Environment: VS2013 SP4, NUnit, NSubstitute, .NET Framework 4.5.1.

I wonder what can be the reason of this behavior, when call of another method from Equals doesn't happen.

The code:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ObjectEqualsTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CollectionAddRemoveEntityTest()
    {
        const int id = 12345;

        var list = new List<MyObject>();

        var firstObject = Substitute.For<MyObject>();
        firstObject.Id.Returns(id);

        list.Add(firstObject);

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(firstObject), "Cannot find the first object");

        var secondObjectWithSameId = Substitute.For<MyObject>();
        secondObjectWithSameId.Id.Returns(id);

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(secondObjectWithSameId), "Cannot find the second object");

        list.Remove(secondObjectWithSameId);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, list.Count, "Object was not removed from the list");
    }
}

public class MyObject : EntityBase<int>
{
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; }
}

public class EntityBase<TId> : IEntity<TId>, IEquatable<EntityBase<TId>>
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as EntityBase<TId>;

        // if to remove next two lines, the test passes
        return Equals(other);                       // the first implementation
        return EqualsWithDifferentName(other);      // first attempt to fix 

        // second attempt to fix by duplicating the code
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            var otherType = other.GetUnproxfiedType();
            var thisType = GetUnproxfiedType();
            return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) && otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
        }

        return false;

    }

    private Type GetUnproxfiedType()
    {
        return GetType();
    }

    private static bool IsTransient(EntityBase<TId> obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Equals(obj.Id, default(TId));
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(EntityBase<TId> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            var otherType = other.GetUnproxfiedType();
            var thisType = GetUnproxfiedType();
            return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) && otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public virtual bool EqualsWithDifferentName(EntityBase<TId> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            var otherType = other.GetUnproxfiedType();
            var thisType = GetUnproxfiedType();
            return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) && otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Equals(Id, default(TId)) ? base.GetHashCode() : Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
Instead of using Substitute.For<> one should use Substitute.ForPartsOf<>.

When proxy is created with For<> it overrides all methods that can be overridden. In this case Equals(EntityBase<>) had empty implementation and the debugger could not step into this method.

Option with removing virtual keyword from method declaration may not work when the object is used with ORM which requires virtual on every method and property (I mean NHibernate).

Comment: UPDATE: after changing Substitute.For<MyObject>(); to Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyObject>(); test passes.

Another option is to remove virtual, but it maybe required by NHibernate or other ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it

```
[TestFixture]
public class ObjectEqualsTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CollectionAddRemoveEntityTest()
    {
        const int id = 12345;

        var list = new List<MyObject>();

        var firstObject = Substitute.For<MyObject>();
        firstObject.Id.Returns(id);

        list.Add(firstObject);

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(firstObject), "Cannot find the first object");

        var secondObjectWithSameId = Substitute.For<MyObject>();
        secondObjectWithSameId.Id.Returns(id);

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains(secondObjectWithSameId), "Cannot find the second object");

        list.Remove(secondObjectWithSameId);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, list.Count, "Object was not removed from the list");
    }
}

public class MyObject : EntityBase<int>
{
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; }
}

public class EntityBase<TId> : IEntity<TId>
{
    public virtual TId Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        EntityBase<TId> otherEntity = other as EntityBase<TId>;
        if ((object)otherEntity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals(otherEntity);
    }

    public bool Equals(EntityBase<TId> other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!IsTransient(this) && !IsTransient(other) && Equals(Id, other.Id))
        {
            var otherType = other.GetUnproxfiedType();
            var thisType = GetUnproxfiedType();
            return thisType.IsAssignableFrom(otherType) && otherType.IsAssignableFrom(thisType);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Equals(Id, default(TId)) ? base.GetHashCode() : Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    private Type GetUnproxfiedType()
    {
        return GetType();
    }

    private static bool IsTransient(EntityBase<TId> obj)
    {
        return obj != null && Equals(obj.Id, default(TId));
    }
}
```

Right now test passes

The hole point is to omit `virtual` statement in `public bool Equals(EntityBase<TId> other)` . Probably NSubstitute proxy has own implementation of that method.

Comment: Thank, nice idea.

I think the problem was that I didn't use NSubstitute correctly and instead of Substitute.For<> I use now Substitute.ForPartsOf<>. It fixes the problem even with virtual methods.

I will check the proxy generated by EF and update this post if there are any problems or strange behavior.

Comment: Ok. If my answer helps you please mark it as solution. If not we should think a little bit more.